# XMPPFramework finishing file transfer

Tags: swift, xmppframework

I'm using [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) with my project and I'm trying to send a photo each other, but I'm stuck.

The file transfer works very well at first time, but when trying to send another one, It fails with message "Transfer already in progress".

I searched a lot, but there's no description/advice/answer for this case. How should I solve this?

My code is here :

*Start sending with pressing the button.*

```
@IBAction func didPressedSendButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if imageView.image == nil{
        print("Select image first!")
        return
    }
    if jidField.text == nil{
        print("Set opponent jid first!")
        return
    }
    if !XMPP.shared.stream.isConnected{
        print("Stream is not connected!")
        return
    }

    sender.isEnabled = false

    let outgoingFileTransfer = XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer(dispatchQueue: .main)
    outgoingFileTransfer.activate(XMPP.shared.stream)
    outgoingFileTransfer.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: .main)

    let opponent = XMPPJID(string: jidField.text!)!
    let recipient = XMPPJID(user: opponent.user, domain: opponent.domain, resource: "foo")

    do{
        outgoingFileTransfer.recipientJID = recipient

        outgoingFileTransfer.outgoingData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)

        try outgoingFileTransfer.start()

        try outgoingFileTransfer.send(
            UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!),
            named: imageView.image?.description ,
            toRecipient: recipient,
            description: "outgoingFileTransfer Description")

    }catch{
        print("Uh-oh... Something went wrong.")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

*Delegate methods*

```
func xmppOutgoingFileTransfer(_ sender: XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print("There was an error for sending a file. \(error.localizedDescription)")

    sendButton.isEnabled = true
}

func xmppOutgoingFileTransferDidSucceed(_ sender: XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer!) {
    print("Sending a file succeed. pray for receiving with no problem.")
    sendButton.isEnabled = true
}

func xmppIncomingFileTransfer(_ sender: XMPPIncomingFileTransfer!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print("Incoming file transfer failed with error : ", error)
}

func xmppIncomingFileTransfer(_ sender: XMPPIncomingFileTransfer!, didReceiveSIOffer offer: XMPPIQ!) {

    print("Incoming File Transfer did receive SI Offer. Accepting...")

    print("Offer : ")
    print(offer.prettyXMLString())

    sender.acceptSIOffer(offer)
    //offer.name
}

func xmppIncomingFileTransfer(_ sender: XMPPIncomingFileTransfer!, didSucceedWith data: Data!, named name: String!) {

    print("I got something...")

    if let receivedString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You\'ve got :", message: receivedString, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("OK, this is a text file.")
        print("Incoming file transfer did Succeed. Hooray!")
    }else if let receivedImage = UIImage(data: data){
        receivedImageview.image = receivedImage

        print("OK, this is an image file.")
        print("Incoming file transfer did Succeed. Hooray!")
    }else{
        print("I got something, but I can\'t convert it. what is this?")
    }

}
```

+++ Additional

I "succeed" to send & receive a first file, But I can't send a second one. It just returns an error message "Transfer already in progress", and file transferring never starts.

Comment: How quickly do you do the second file? You may be running into a race condition between `transferSuccess` and `cleanUp`.

Comment: Idk how quick does second file do the transfer. It doesn't attempt to send, just an error message shows up. "Transfer already in progress". But, I'm using a small size of image for testing(about 300x300), I think it doesn't matter with this problem.

Comment: I mean if you start the second one before the first one is really really finished, it won't work. I looked through the source code.

Comment: Yes It won't finished unless entire of first one is fully transferred 'cause I didn't put a code to end a stream. But what I want is "How to end up the stream after receiving all data". I couldn't find any method to do it.

Comment: There's even a delegate method: `- (void)xmppOutgoingFileTransferIBBClosed:(XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer *)sender;`

Comment: Yup there's a delegate method, but it can't closes stream right? It's just a delegate method when transferring has closed

Comment: I read `XmppOutgoingFileTransfer.m`'s code and there was no method for me to close the stream. or I missed something?

Comment: hi @CyanLee i am also face this issue.if you know solution for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

just remove this code:

```
    try outgoingFileTransfer.start()
```